# Number of divs with same class using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I find the number of divs with a specific class name using jquery

like here I would like to get the result as 2 for class name "failedtest". and I also want to access them through the id of outer div (1285766787423container)

```
<div id="1285766787423container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
        </div>
        <div class="failedtest">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
        </div>
        <div class="failedtest">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
        </div>
        <div class="cell2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
        </div>
        <div class="cell2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="1285766787423container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
        </div>
        <div class="failedtest">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
        </div>
        <div class="failedtest">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
        </div>
        <div class="cell2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
        </div>
        <div class="cell2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing the </div> which closes the container div.

Comment: You've reused the same ID in your example. I assume in your actual code the IDs will be unique. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#1285766787423container div.failedtest").size();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var numberOfFailedDivs = $('#1285766787423container .failedtest').length;
```

or if you want only the `div` elements with this class:

```
var numberOfFailedDivs = $('#1285766787423container div.failedtest').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("#1285766787423container div.failedtest").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#1285766787423container div.failedtest").size();
```